# connection time out:connect consult IDE log

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, ide, kotlin

I have android studio 3 canary, I'm programming with Kotlin , I use windows 64 bit OS, when I want to start a new project I'm getting this error in xml files , and I can't view design for project...

please Help me if you have any idea!! thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apparently you have no connection.

Comment: please what's the solution , i have connection ??

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment(s), you literally have no internet connection which is mandatory for gradle building since the platform checks for potential updates for say, SDK versions, from a server.

However, if you want to build and do your work offline, then go to **File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Check Offline work under Global Gradle settings**

Comment: but when i use offline work  , i have another broblem
==> https://www.gulf-up.com/do.php?img=330026

Comment: @Soufiane.bekk Strange. But then again, you should expect bugs when using Android Studio's alpha version, and this could be one of them. That's why I still use Android Studio's latest stable version (2.3.3 as of now) for a reason.